# Infowindows on Google map loading before map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I have a google map which has multiple markers pulled from a custom post type.

They also have info windows containing information from each post, but when the page is loading the infowindows/markers appear before the map does.

Is there a way I can set it so that the markers/infowindows only show once the map has fully loaded? Or have a screen which is shown until it's loaded?

I've attached a couple of screen grabs to show what I mean

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't see any images attached. It would also help if you included the relevant parts of your current code, to help understand how you're embedding the map.

Comment: Please share the google script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, sorry about that, I solved it by adding css display:none to my marker div, this stopped them from all loading down the page but they all still worked on load